# How to add icons to an infowindow on a google map marker

Tags: javascript

Hello I am currently learning how to code on JavaScript and I have a problem. I want to add a line separator and some icons to my code so when you click the marker it shows a window with that info.

```
function createMarker(latlng, name, address, phone, status, index){
    var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + status + "<br/>" + address + "<br/>" + phone;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: latlng,
      label: index.toString()
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infoWindow.setContent(html);
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    markers.push(marker);
```

this is my code so far

and I want it to look like the example: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KtMaFoN07bJQtKvKME_YMOoVcaZOvDkg/view?fbclid=IwAR1wEWAuQDaB1SUJlILd4wcLMHBbgtQmhqmSTWMKosN62TdOiRLW3i6clVc

Comment: Show what happens at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one sir. You can customize your infowindow design using the `html` element tag. I hope you can get an idea to fix your problem. Thanks :D

```
function createMarker(latlng, name, address, phone, status, index){

        //var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + status + "<br/>" + address + "<br/>" + phone;

        // e.g

        var html = '<p style=""><img src="" alt=""><strong>Header Title</strong></p>'+
                    '<p style="text-align:center">'+name+'</p>'+
                    '<p style="font-size:11px">'+status+'</p>'+
                    '<p style="font-size:11px">'+address+'</p>'+
                    '<p style="font-size:11px">'+phone+'</p>';

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: latlng,
          label: index.toString()
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infoWindow.setContent(html);
          infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        markers.push(marker);

    }
```